# Dynamic generic parameters that return generic type in closure?

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

I'm trying to achieve a simple API for a complex scenario. I have a type that retrieves data asynchronously (bluetooth device actually). So the API I'm trying to end up with is this:

```
peripheral.requestData(.Temperature) { value: Double in
    print(value)
}
```

I got some good ideas from [this amazing article](http://radex.io/swift/nsuserdefaults/static/), so this is what I attempted to achieve the above:

```
class MyPeripheral {

    class Keys {
        static let Temperature = PeripheralKey<Double>("Temperature")
        static let UserData = PeripheralKey<[String: String]>("UserData")
    }

    func requestData(service: Keys, handler: (value: ???Get ValueType from PeripheralKey???) -> Void) {
        if let service = service as? PeripheralKey<Int> {
            service.key //Do something
        } else if let service = service as? PeripheralKey<[String: String]>
            //Do something else
        }
    }
}

class PeripheralKey<ValueType>: MyPeripheral.Keys {
    let key: String

    init(_ key: String) {
        self.key = key
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble with the closure type that is returned. I want to be strongly typed based on the peripheral generic type key that was passed in, but can't grasp how to do that, or maybe need a different approach? Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generic parameter in oder to get the value type of your `service`. In order to use it statically I suggest to use `PeripheralKey<T>` instead of its subclass:

```
class MyPeripheral {

    class Keys {
        static let Temperature = PeripheralKey<Double>("Temperature")
        static let UserData = PeripheralKey<[String: String]>("UserData")
    }

    // use a generic parameter T
    func requestData<T>(service: PeripheralKey<T>, handler: (value: T) -> Void) {
        // if you do similar things like in your posted link
        // you can use ("data" has to be defined by you):
        // data[service.key] as! T
    }
}

// make class final as long as you don't subclass it
final class PeripheralKey<ValueType>: MyPeripheral.Keys {
    let key: String

    init(_ key: String) {
        self.key = key
    }
}

let peripheral = MyPeripheral()
// here you can omit the explicit Double declaration
peripheral.requestData(.Temperature) { value in
    print(value)
}
```

After Swift 3.0 got released you can likely put static properties in generic types which allows you to use only one struct like this:

```
struct PeripheralKey<ValueType> {

    static let Temperature = PeripheralKey<Double>("Temperature")
    static let UserData = PeripheralKey<[String: String]>("UserData")

    let key: String

    init(_ key: String) {
        self.key = key
    }
}
```